# Failed query in mysql Database

Tags: php, mysql

Good afternoon, 
I dont get to see any error in my code and i have been getting Mysql Errors along the line.

My code looks like this

```
<?php
include 'account_numgen.php';
require_once('inc/config.php');

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass, $db)or die ('Cannot Connect :'.mysqli_error());

$account_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['account_number']);
$first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['first_name']);
$mi = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['mi']);
$last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['last_name']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['address']);
$address2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['address2']);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['city']);
$tel = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['tel']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
$nok_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['nok_1']);
$nok1_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['nok1_address']);
$nok1_address2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['nok1_address2']);
$nok1_city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['nok1_city']);
$nok_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['nok_2']);
$nok2_address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['nok2_address']);
$nok2_address2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['nok2_address2']);
$nok2_city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['nok2_city']);
$id_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['id_type']);
$id_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['id_number']);
$open_bal = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['open_bal']);
$passport_name = $_FILES['passport']['name'];
$passport_size = $_FILES['passport']['size'];
$passport_type = $_FILES['passport']['type'];
$passporttmp_name = $_FILES['passport']['tmp_name'];

$signature_name = $_FILES['signature']['name'];
$signature_size = $_FILES['signature']['size'];
$signature_type = $_FILES['signature']['type'];
$signaturetmp_name = $_FILES['signature']['tmp_name'];

$sql = "insert into bank_details(account_number,first_name,mi,last_name,address,address2,city,tel,email,nok_1,nok1_address,nok1_address2,nok1_city,nok_2,nok2_address,nok2_address2,nok2_city,id_type,id_number,open_bal,passport_name,passport_size,passport_type,passporttmp_name,signature_name,signature_size,signature_type,signaturetmp_name) values ('".$account_number."','".$first_name."','".$mi."','".$last_name."','".$address."','".$address2."','".$city."','".$tel."','".$email."','".$nok_1."','".$nok1_address."','".$nok1_address2."','".$nok1_city."','".$nok_2."','".$nok2_address."','".$nok2_address2."','".$nok2_city."','".$id_type."','".$id_number."','".$open_bal."','".$passport_name."','".$passport_size."','".$passport_type."','".$passporttmp_name."','".$signature_name."','".$signature_size."','".$signature_type."','".$signaturetmp_name."')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die ('Failed Query: '.mysqli_error($con));

$passport_dir = 'passport/';
$signature_dir = 'signature/';

$filePath1 = $passport_dir . $passport_name;
$filePath2 = $signature_dir . $signature_name;

$result1 = move_uploaded_file($passporttmp_name,$filePath1);
$result2 = move_uploaded_file($signaturetmp_name,$filePath2);

echo ('
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
   window.alert("Account Information \n Account Number: '.$account_number.'\n First Name: '.$first_name.'\n Last Name: '.$last_name.'\n Last Name: '.$open_bal.'")
   window.location.href="index.html";
</SCRIPT>
');

?>
```

Now i get this Error

```
Failed Query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 's_Signature.png','78716','image/png','C:\xampp\tmp\phpD784.tmp')' at line 1
```

Why is this so? i dont get to see any errors in My code, How ever it has stopped posting to the database on My Local host.

**Edit**

When i add `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_FILES[....])` it works fine, but it doesnt send the images from the application to the localhost server what exactly can be the case?

Comment: is your enter key broken? Try a few time enter on this 200 character long line containing your query. You will then get the same error, but on on line 1, but on line X. Finding your error will become easier. Probably a missing ' it will be

Comment: Do an `echo $sql` and output the query actually being sent to the DB. The error is in the data portion so we can't help you without that

Comment: Also, switch to [prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/2784/php-mysqli/11958/prepared-statements-in-mysqli) and you won't have this problem

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` on all the fields, including what you get in `$_FILES`

Apparently there is a quote in the name...
And the way you used it the path would be wrong, because it should be `\\` instead of every `\`, otherwise `\t` is a tab.

Answer (score 0):

`$signature_name` has an apostrophe ('). You need to escape it too with `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

I recommend to escape all parameters of a query besides use prepared statements. Check this out https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

**Edit:** As sugested by Accountant

Escape all parameters OR use prepared statements. In fact, you should always use prepared statements, they escape the parameters for you, amongst other things.

Comment: Why escape the parameters if you are going to use a prepared statement? you can safely use the input directly without escaping it if you are using a prepared statement.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_real_escape_string` on '`$signature_name` ' - it has an apostrophe in it.

```
$signature_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_FILES['signature']['name']);
```